# What is the function of "as" in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

> China is not in crisis. However, its ability to evolve smoothly from a command to a market economy is in question as never before.

What is the function of "as" in the sentence above? What is the meaning of "as never before"?

Comment: Conjunction. It's shortened from *as (it has) never (been) before.*

Answer (score 1):

Meaning: *as never before* = *like never before*

Function: **preposition**

Answer (score 0):

the meaning is `in a way that has never been ​possible before`

as for the grammar, `as` is, here, a subordinating conjunction

Examples :

```
She shook her head and sighed as she puzzled over the algebra problem.

As I was walking, I came across a lost wallet

As the weather started heating up, I took off my jacket
```

Comment: true, but I thought "in a way that has never been ​possible before" implied the temporality. As in "it wouldn't have happened in the past, but now is happening"

Comment: You're right.  I was distracted by the "never been possible."  I've deleted my initial comment as unhelpful.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please give me more examples how to use 'as' in the sense of a subordinating conjunction?

Comment: added some examples

Answer (score 0):

The function word as has multiple uses.

- She did **as** she was told.

Here "as" introduces a clause of comparison.

Answer (score 0):

In the interpretation, "as never before" modifies "in question" -- it tells you how much the ability is in question.  The "as" phrase could be paraphrased by "greatly", which is an adverb.  By McCawley's rule, a modifier of something other than a noun is an adverb.  (Possibly an adverbial or adverb phrase -- that's not clear.)

"Never before" means that something never before happened, so its meaning is that of a sentence.  Assuming it is also grammatically a sentence, that makes the grammatical function of "as" a converter of a sentence ("never before") into an adverb ("as never before").

In categorial grammar, consequently, we could write down the category of "as" as Adverb/Sentence.  In traditional grammar, I suppose we could make "as" a subordinate conjunction.

I'm not sure "never before" is really a sentence.  "Never before happened" can be substituted, and that appears to be a verb phrase "happened" modified by an adverb "never before", which would make it a verb phrase instead of a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

...is in question now *to a greater extent than* it has ever been in question in the past.

**After seven days in the woods with nothing to eat, he was so hungry that he enjoyed a simple bowl of soup as never before.**